# upload photo to facebook issue. Wrong photo orientation

Tags: iphone, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I upload photoes to facebook.
If photo width > heigh, everything is OK. 
But if height > width, facebook turns up the photo, so in facebook account photo appears with width > height, but (of course) orientation is wrong.
My code:

```
- (void)postImageToFaceBook:(UIImage *)imgSource
{
    [self login];

    currentAPICall = kAPIGraphUserPhotosPost;

    NSString *strMessage = @"This is the photo caption";
    NSMutableDictionary* photosParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         imgSource,@"source",
                                         strMessage,@"message",
                                         nil];

    NSLog(@"Begin sending photo\n\n");
    [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                          andParams:photosParams
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)login
{
    if (![_facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"user_photos",
                                nil];
        [_facebook authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];
    }
}

- (void)logout
{
    [_facebook logout];
}


#pragma mark - FBRequestDelegate

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSLog(@"Request load\n\n");
    [self hideHud];

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && ([result count] > 0)) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    switch (currentAPICall) {
        case kAPIGraphPhotoData: // step 3
        {
            NSLog(@"sending to wall\n\n");
            // Facebook doesn't allow linking to images on fbcdn.net.  So for now use default thumb stored on Picasa

            NSString *thumbURL = kDefaultThumbURL;
            NSString *imageLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:[result objectForKey:@"link"]];    

            currentAPICall = kDialogFeedUser;


            NSMutableDictionary* dialogParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 kAppId, @"app_id",
                                                 imageLink, @"link",
                                                 thumbURL, @"picture",
                                                 @"Photo from my iPhone application", @"name",
                                                 @"The app", @"caption",
                                                 @"it is fun to use", @"description",
                                                 nil];

            [_facebook dialog:@"feed" 
                    andParams:dialogParams 
                  andDelegate:self];


            break;
        }
        case kAPIGraphUserPhotosPost: // step 2
        {
            NSLog(@"getting data\n\n");
            [self showHudWithMessage:@"Getting image data"];
            NSString *imageID = [NSString stringWithFormat:[result objectForKey:@"id"]];            
            NSLog(@"id of uploaded screen image %@",imageID);

            currentAPICall = kAPIGraphPhotoData;

            [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:imageID
                                andDelegate:self];

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}


#pragma mark - FBDialogDelegate

- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {
    switch (currentAPICall) {
        case kDialogFeedUser:
        {
            NSLog(@"Feed published successfully.");
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In postImageToFaceBook I checked image size to be completely shure that my image width < height. Width is about 2200, height is 3300, and facebook album image appears with width > height.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you see if the photo's Exif Tag is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
This behavio is when image is about 2000 px width, but if the width is less then 1000 px, everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Actually facebook not doing anything on Image. iPhone display all images in Portrait mode event it is on Landscape mode. So please check image on your system.

Thanks

Comment: No, in postImageToFaceBook I checked image size, width is about 2200, height is 3300, and facebook album image appears with width > height. I updated the post

Comment: Have you checked image in your System. Bcoz few days back I also faced same problem. and be sure you are not doing image resize before upload it on fb.

Comment: After I checked width is about 2200, height is 3300, I don't resize image. What do you mean "Have you checked image in your System". As I said before, I checked image size, before sending it.

Comment: Actually Image always looks fine in device. so please copy this image in your PC and check is it in portrait or landscape?

Comment: Ok, I added image to Libriary (in postImageToFaceBook). Then copied to PC. It's portrait.

Comment: @MiteshKhatri, i faced the same problem. I actually resized the photo. Why it gets wrong when i resized the photo? How to fix it?